# Adding a Time to a Date stamp before posting to Firebase

Tags: forms, flutter, datetime, google-cloud-firestore

I have a current issue now that the UK has entered daylight savings (i.e. moved from UTC to UTC+1).

Dates that are stored as, for example 31st March 00:00:00 UTC+1 are being read as 30th March 23:00:00 UTC. The app is reading the dates correctly when displaying to the user, but I have a notification system that is sending notifications on the wrong date as a result.

The date comes from a Form Builder field. I don't want the time shown to the user, just the date, but what I want to do is post this date to the Firestore Collection with a 2am time. For example if the user entered 31st March 2021 - I want 31st March 2021 02:00:00 added to the Collection.

How best can I do this?

**My Form Builder code is:**

```
FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
                                attribute: 'dateChosen',
                                onChanged: _onChanged,
                                inputType: InputType.date,
                                format: DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Add Date',
                                ),
                                validator: (val) => null,
                                initialValue: DateTime.now(),
                                validators: [
                                  FormBuilderValidators.required(),
                                  (val) {
                                    if (val.compareTo(DateTime.now()) < 0)
                                      return "The end date must not be in the past";
                                  },
                                ],
                              ),
```

**The code posting this to the Collection is as follows:**

```
_firestore
                                            .collection(
                                                'thisCollection')
                                            .add({
                                          'Type': 'Niche',
                                          'nicheName': _fbKey
                                              .currentState.value['nicheName'],
                                          'Date': _fbKey
                                              .currentState.value['dateChosen'],
                                          'Posted': DateTime.now(),
                                          'uid': getCurrentUID(),
                                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/serverTimestamp.html).

For example:

```
'Posted': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
```